# get one record based upon catname

Tags: mysql

I have this query, it joins two tables and give me results of all the data under one a condition `CATID` is

> 'videography'

```
SELECT
pm_categories_images.Image,
pm_categories_images.FileURL,
pm_categories.catname,
pm_categories.`status`,
pm_categories.sortorder,
pm_categories.parentID,
pm_categories_images.CatID
FROM
pm_categories
LEFT JOIN pm_categories_images ON pm_categories_images.CatID = pm_categories.catID 
where pm_categories_images.CatID IN (select catid from pm_categories where 
parentID = (select catID from pm_categories where catname = 'Videography'))
```

Now this videography has a results like this

> http://prntscr.com/gpkuyl

now i want to get `1` record for every `catname`

Comment: Any particular "record" or just "a record"?  ( like the most recent, the one with the highest parentID, the one with the lowest sort order?  what?  mySQL extends the group by so you could `group by catName` but I don't think that's really what you want

Comment: the first one of each one will suffice

Comment: Well database tables don't have an order; you have to set one.  So by first do you mean the one with the lowest sort order?  Additionally where where clause is negating the left join as only images which have a pm_Category would be displayed.  Lastly, what is the Primary key for PM_Categories?

Comment: yes, with the lowest sort order, left join is used to attach images which are a part of different table

Comment: ? http://rextester.com/CRBN50943  Well, since sort order is on categories, it's not a good column to limit.  Since I can only see image, fileurl and cat ID on cat_Images, I can only assume a min or max image would suffice. so link attached shows a possibilty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and actual requirements on which image you want from the images table and a better understanding of why you need a left join when your where clause makes it behave like an inner... and why the where clause is so complex... ...I'm really unsure what the question is after... Here's a shot... and a DEMO:http://rextester.com/CRBN50943

Sample data expected results always a plus: I made my own and several assumptions

I interperted the question as: I would like a list of the categories along with a image having the earliest alphabetic value for each category.

```
SELECT
CI.Image,
CI.FileURL,
C.catname,
C.`status`,
C.sortorder,
C.parentID,
CI.CatID
FROM pm_categories C
INNER JOIN pm_categories_images  CI
  ON CI.CatID = C.catID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Min(Image) MI, catID FROM pm_categories_images group by CATID) Z
 on CI.Image = Z.MI 
 and CI.CatID = Z.CatId
##WHERE C.catname = 'Videography'
Order by sortOrder
```

Giving us

```
+----+------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+-------+
|    |   Image    |                    FileURL                    |   catname   | status | sortorder | parentID | CatID |
+----+------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+-------+
|  1 | guid1.jpg  | https://drive.google.com/BusinessID/Postings/ | Real Estate |      1 |         1 | NULL     |     1 |
|  2 | guid4.jpg  | https://drive.google.com/BusinessID/Postings/ | commercial  |      1 |         2 | NULL     |     2 |
|  3 | guid6.jpg  | https://drive.google.com/BusinessID/Postings/ | Videography |      1 |         3 | NULL     |     3 |
|  4 | guid10.jpg | https://drive.google.com/BusinessID/Postings/ | Other       |      1 |         4 | NULL     |     4 |
|  5 | guid11.jpg | https://drive.google.com/BusinessID/Postings/ | LackingMCVE |      1 |         5 | NULL     |     5 |
+----+------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+-------+
```